# Problems with GroovyShell and propertyMissing()

Tags: groovy, dsl, groovyshell

I'm having problems using `propertyMissing()` together with `GroovyShell`

I have the files

```
/**
 * @file FooScript.groovy
 */
abstract class FooScript extends Script {

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        "This is the property '$name'"
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
        println "You tried to set property '$name' to '$value'"
    }
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @file FooScriptTest.groovy
 */

import org.codehaus.groovy.control.*


def fooScript = """\
                foo = 'bar'
                println foo"""

def conf = new CompilerConfiguration()
conf.setScriptBaseClass("FooScript")
def sh = new GroovyShell(conf)

sh.evaluate fooScript
```

When I run `FooScriptTest.groovy` I expect the output

> You tried to set property 'foo' to 'bar'
>
> This is the property 'foo'

What I get is:

> bar

Seems my `propertyMissing()` is overridden by the default one. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this instead

```
abstract class BarScript extends Script {
  def getProperty(String name) {
    "This is the property '$name'"
  }
  void setProperty(String name, value) {
    println "You tried to set property '$name' to '$value'"
  }
}
```

`missingProperty` methods are the last resource to catch a property access,
tested only when everything else has failed.
but `groovy.lang.Script` already implements the higher priority methods `get/setProperty`.
so to catch a missing property, these are the methods you have to override in your subclass